# How to print the number corresponding to the maximum frequency in array in C++?

Tags: c++

Given below is the code I wrote. So the problem is that it's incomplete and not optimised. Please help me!

```cpp
int main()
{
    long long n, i, j;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[] = {2,3,2,2,2,5,2};
    int count[n];
    int max = 1
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)     
        {
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                count[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't actually have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which makes your code invalid. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: What's the purpose of `max` ? Just curious.

Comment: What's the purpose of `n` when you're counting an array with seven elements?

Comment: Is the missing semi-colon on the declaration of `max` intentional?

Comment: There is no problem description here. What happens when you compile/run this code? Why is that bad? What should happen instead?

Comment: Don't worry mate, C++ is hard to start with and needs a lot of practice :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you dont need to iterate over the entire array every time you search. You can search from the i-th element for elements similar to it from that point. Every time you reach a count > current_max, update the current max.
Hope that clears things out.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities. One is to use standard c arrays and the other uses `std::vector<int>`

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int maxFreq(int* arr, unsigned len)
{
    int res = 0;
    std::unordered_map<int,int> freqCounter;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        res = std::max(res, ++freqCounter[arr[i]]);
    
    return res;
}

int maxFreq(const std::vector<int>& arr)
{
    int res = 0;
    std::unordered_map<int,int> freqCounter;
    
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
        res = std::max(res, ++freqCounter[arr[i]]);
    
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to sort the array and then count how many of each value you find next to each other.

Your array, sorted, would be:

```
2 2 2 2 2 3 5
```

If you draw this on a plain paper and try to figure out how to find the one which is most frequent, it'll probably be easy.

- initialize `maxcount = -1` - no number will appear a negative amount of times
- count 2's, got 5. Is 5 more than -1? Yes, set `maxcount = 5` and `maxvalue = 2`
- count 3's, got 1. Is 1 more than 5? No, continue.
- count 5's, got 1. Is 1 more than 5? No, continue ... oh, done.

You can implement the above using what you've learned already and if sorting is new, lookup [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It's a really easy to understand (and inefficent) sorting algorithm that gets the job done.

If you are free to use C++'s standard library, it could be implemented like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {   
    int arr[]={2,3,2,2,2,5,2};

    // sort the array
    std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    // print the sorted array
    // for(auto v : arr) std::cout << v << ' '; std::cout << '\n';

    // the variables keeping track of the "best so far":
    int maxcount = -1;
    int maxvalue{};

    // loop over the array using an iterator (most likely an `int*` here):
    for(auto it = std::begin(arr); it != std::end(arr); ) {
        // dereference the iterator to get the value
        auto v = *it;     // will be 2, 3, 5 in your case

        // count how many `v`s there are in a row by finding the first place
        // where the value is _not_ `v`:
        auto endit = std::find_if_not(it, std::end(arr),
                                     [&v](auto& t){ return v==t; });

        // get the distance between the two iterators, which is exactly
        // how many `v`'s there are in the array
        auto n = std::distance(it, endit);        

        if(n > maxcount) { // have we found a new maximum?
            maxcount = n;  // store this new maximum
            maxvalue = v;
        }

        it = endit; // set `it` to point at the first non-`v` in the array
    }

    std::cout << maxvalue << " appeared " << maxcount << " times\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. For the more advanced readers, I will show a more modern C++ solution using the best fitting containers from the STL.

The standard approach for counting occurences of elements in a container is to use a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`. By using its index operator, counting can be done in a very short one liner.

And then, and maybe not many people know this, we can use a maxheap to get one or more "biggest" elements. A [maxheap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) in C++ will be implemented via a `std::priority_queue`

Then the whole functionality can be implemented by 2 or 3 lines of code.

Please see the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

// Predicate Functor. Compare 2 std::pairs. 2nd part.
struct LessForSecondOfPair {
    bool operator () (const std::pair<int, size_t>& p1, const std::pair<int, size_t>& p2) { return p1.second < p2.second; }
};

int main() {

    // The test data
    int test[] = { 4,6,1,2,5,6,2,6,3,5,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6, };

    // Some abbreviation for easier reading
    using Counter = std::unordered_map<int, size_t>;
    using MaxHeap = std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, size_t>, std::vector<std::pair<int, size_t>>, LessForSecondOfPair>;

    // Count all occurences of data
    Counter counter{};
    for (const auto& i : test) counter[i]++;

    // Build a Max-Heap
    MaxHeap maxHeap(counter.begin(), counter.end());

    // Show result
    return (bool) (std::cout << "\n\nMost frequent used number is: " << maxHeap.top().first << "\n\n");
}
```

So, a very clean and simple solution. Based on C++17

If you need also to show the count, then return the `.second` element of the `top`.

You can of course also pop more values from the heap.

If you want to have a more generic solution for any kind of iterable container with any datatype, you could use (with C++20) enabled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

// Some Alias names for later easier reading --------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
using ValueType = std::ranges::range_value_t<Container>;

template <typename Container>
using Pair = std::pair<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;

template <typename Container>
using Counter = std::unordered_map<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;

template <typename Container>
using UnderlyingContainer = std::vector<Pair<Container>>;

// Predicate Functor
template <class Container> struct LessForSecondOfPair {
    bool operator ()(const Pair<Container>& p1, const Pair<Container>& p2) { return p1.second < p2.second; }
};

template <typename Container>
using MaxHeap = std::priority_queue<Pair<Container>, UnderlyingContainer<Container>, LessForSecondOfPair<Container>>;

// Calculate max element ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Container>
auto topFrequent(const Container& data) {
    if constexpr (std::ranges::range<Container>) {
        // Count all occurences of data
        Counter<Container> counter{};
        for (const auto& d : data) counter[d]++;

        // Build a Max-Heap
        MaxHeap<Container> maxHeap(counter.begin(), counter.end());

        // Return most frequent number
        return maxHeap.top().first;
    }
    else
        return data;
}

// Test
int main() {
    std::vector testVector{ 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7 };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(testVector) << "\n";

    double cStyleArray[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3 };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(cStyleArray) << "\n";

    std::string s{ "abbcccddddeeeeeffffffggggggg" };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(s) << "\n";

    double value = 12.34;
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(value) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

So, and if we do not have C++ 20 concepts for iterable ranges (`std::ranges::range`), then we can build our own type traits. Hence, the following will work with C++17:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

// Helper for type trait We want to identify an iterable container ----------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
auto isIterableHelper(int) -> decltype (
    std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()) != std::end(std::declval<Container&>()),     // begin/end and operator !=
    ++std::declval<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()))&>(),                // operator ++
    void(*std::begin(std::declval<Container&>())),                                      // operator*
    void(),                                                                             // Handle potential operator ,
    std::true_type{});
template <typename T>
std::false_type isIterableHelper(...);

// The type trait -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
using is_iterable = decltype(isIterableHelper<Container>(0));

// Some Alias names for later easier reading --------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
using ValueType = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()))>;
template <typename Container>
using Pair = std::pair<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;
template <typename Container>
using Counter = std::unordered_map<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;

// Function to get the k most frequent elements used  in any Container ------------------------------------------------
template <class Container>
auto topKFrequent(const Container& data, size_t k) {

    if constexpr (is_iterable<Container>::value) {

        // Count all occurences of data
        Counter<Container> counter{};
        for (const auto& d : data) counter[d]++;

        // For storing the top k
        std::vector<Pair<Container>> top(k);

        // Get top k
        std::partial_sort_copy(counter.begin(), counter.end(), top.begin(), top.end(),
            [](const std::pair<int, size_t >& p1, const std::pair<int, size_t>& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; });

        return top;
    }
    else
        return data;
}
int main() {
    std::vector testVector{ 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7 };
    for (const auto& p : topKFrequent(testVector, 2)) std::cout << "Value: " << p.first << " \t Count: " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    double cStyleArray[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3 };
    for (const auto& p : topKFrequent(cStyleArray, 2)) std::cout << "Value: " << p.first << " \t Count: " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::string s{ "abbcccddddeeeeeffffffggggggg" };
    for (const auto& p : topKFrequent(s, 2)) std::cout << "Value: " << p.first << " \t Count: " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    double value = 12.34;
    std::cout << topKFrequent(value, 2) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

As written above, you can get more values from the heap, if needed. But in that case, the usage of `std::partial_sort_copy` is more advisable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

// Helper for type trait We want to identify an iterable container ----------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
auto isIterableHelper(int) -> decltype (
    std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()) != std::end(std::declval<Container&>()),     // begin/end and operator !=
    ++std::declval<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()))&>(),                // operator ++
    void(*std::begin(std::declval<Container&>())),                                      // operator*
    void(),                                                                             // Handle potential operator ,
    std::true_type{});
template <typename T>
std::false_type isIterableHelper(...);

// The type trait -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
using is_iterable = decltype(isIterableHelper<Container>(0));

// Some Alias names for later easier reading --------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
using ValueType = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()))>;
template <typename Container>
using Pair = std::pair<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;
template <typename Container>
using Counter = std::unordered_map<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;

// Function to get the k most frequent elements used  in any Container ------------------------------------------------
template <class Container>
auto topKFrequent(const Container& data, size_t k) {

    if constexpr (is_iterable<Container>::value) {

        // Count all occurences of data
        Counter<Container> counter{};
        for (const auto& d : data) counter[d]++;

        // For storing the top k
        std::vector<Pair<Container>> top(k);

        // Get top k
        std::partial_sort_copy(counter.begin(), counter.end(), top.begin(), top.end(),
            [](const std::pair<int, size_t >& p1, const std::pair<int, size_t>& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; });

        return top;
    }
    else
        return data;
}
int main() {
    std::vector testVector{ 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7 };
    for (const auto& p : topKFrequent(testVector, 2)) std::cout << "Value: " << p.first << " \t Count: " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    double cStyleArray[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3 };
    for (const auto& p : topKFrequent(cStyleArray, 2)) std::cout << "Value: " << p.first << " \t Count: " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::string s{ "abbcccddddeeeeeffffffggggggg" };
    for (const auto& p : topKFrequent(s, 2)) std::cout << "Value: " << p.first << " \t Count: " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    double value = 12.34;
    std::cout << topKFrequent(value, 2) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Cool !

What a pity that nobody will read this . . .